# Is this a correct way to do a low voltage cutoff for motorcycle use? (Zener diode + relay)

Tags: relay, automotive, zener

I want to design an electrical component that I would connect to my motorcycle battery. As I do not want it to fully discharge my battery and I want it to run only when my motorcycle alternator is "ON", I want to implement an automatic cutoff when the voltage is below 14V.

In order to do it I use a transistor, a 14V Zener diode and a relay.

Is this a good way to do it? Will the circuit will be completely "off" when the voltage is below 14V (no drain on the battery?)

[image: Circuyit]

Comment: At exactly 14V your going to have some hysterics issues. Have you considered wiring it to a switched power line? What model and year bike?

Comment: This is a recent bike (tiger 900).
The available switched power line is "far away" from where I want to plug this device. To plug my device after a switched power line, I need to remove my motorcycle tank, plastics, etc...

When the bike alternator is running, my voltage is above 14v, so I guess I won't have hysterics issues

Comment: Running an extra wire is an ounce of prevention. And knowing the stator on most bikes and how they are regulated and how they vary based on RPM and load, its not a stable environment. You are better aiming for 13V instead of 14V.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to cut off power to a USB charger when the voltage from your battery/regulator falls below 14V.

> Is this a good way to do it?

Your design will, in fact cut off power to Vcc when the input voltage falls below a certain level. However:

- the Zener diode should have a 13.3 or 13.4V Zener voltage if you want it to trip at 14V. Your circuit actually trips at the Zener voltage plus approximately 0.6-0.7V.
- your circuit may "oscillate" when the voltage is near 14V. The circuit has no hysteresis. If near 14V and the voltage sags, the relay will open. This might allow the voltage to rise just enough to turn the relay back on. Which might cause the voltage to sag etc.
- When your battery / regulator voltage falls below 14V, your USB charger (Vcc) will be completely disconnected. However, a small current will still flow through your circuit. Although the current is small, if the motorcycle is unused for an extended period of time, this current could drain the battery.

The [G5LE-1-DC12](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/307/en-g5le-1131193.pdf) relay requires 33.3mA to operate, and has a coil resistance of 360\$\Omega\$

The [SS8050](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/ss8050-d.pdf) is able to draw 1.5A current, which is quite sufficient for the relay, and has less than 1 uA of leakage current when off. It has a current gain between 40 and 300.

I am unable to find a specification for the forward "off" current of a [2EZ14](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/1284850/PANJIT/2EZ14/1) Zener diode. This is unfortunate, because whatever current leaks through the Zener diode, and is not diverted by R5 will cause a leakage through Q1 between 40 and 300 times greater.

Decreasing the value of R5, may help to decrease current into Q1 when the "line" voltage is below 14V. However, it will (obviously) increase the the leakage through D2 and R5. I believe the sweet spot occurs when the two leakage currents (through Q1 and R5) are equal, (but I haven't checked that).

Comment: You're indicating a leakage through d2 and r5? Or D2 R4 Q1? Like when Vbatt is 12V? How much of a leak (guesstimate)

Comment: @Math Keeps Me Busy the battery will be connected to the +14V terminal.
Should I only increase the resistors value of R4 and R5 ? Or should I also add a resistor "before" Q1 ?

Regarding the oscillate problem, the voltage when my bike alternator is "ON" is above 14V (~14.4V)

Comment: @HWAlex411, I really don't think this is a good idea, but, as you persist: the leakage will be relatively small. It could drain the battery if the bike is unused for a long time. Overnight it should be fine. I haven't done the calculations, but R4 can only be so high before Q1 will not conduct enough to turn on the relay. You want R4 to be less than that amount, but not too much less. The current through the collector of Q1 will be something like 50-200 times that in the base. Adding a resistor to the collector of Q1 risks the relay not turning on. I wouldn't do it.

Comment: @Math Keeps Me Busy Ah ok, sorry I did not understand that increasing the resistor would be a good idea.
I will look for other solutions then to reduce the leakage

NB: I want to add a device on my motorcycle circuit, it won't affect the rest of the electrical components of the bike and so it's legal. My I idea is to connect this device on a hella din plug (which is directly wired to the battery, this is why I simplify my use case)

Comment: may I ask what are you actually trying to prevent from drawing current when the voltage is less than 14V? Lights? Radio? What?

Comment: Yes of course, I would like to power an USB charger.
The hella din available on my motorcycle is directly plugged to the battery and so it is never off. If I forgot to unplug my gps and/or my phone during a stop, it may drain my battery

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood what you were attempting. Do you _only_ want to shut off the USB charger? If so, safety, etc are not the issues I thought they were.

Comment: Yes I only want to shut off the USB charger. Plus I have access to the schematic of the motorcycle wiring and I know this part is totally isolated from the rest of circuits (and so there should not be any unwanted effect on the rest of the bike)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will work.

In the vicinity of the threshold, the NPN may be partially on and therefore dissipate excessive power. At 14 V, this could be approximately (14/2)^2/360 = 0.14 W which is probably OK.

You can add some hysteresis by connecting an R (~ 1 Mohm) from the relay VCC output to the junction of the resistors.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is the quadlock waterproof 12v to USB adaptor. It has a LVCO built in.